# Replace characters in a SELECT only if string ends with certain pattern in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to replace a certain string with a string when doing a SELECT y MySQL, but only if the selected value ends with a specific string, but I don't know even if that's possible in MySQL.

For example, I need to select a field and replace "SL" with "S.L.", but only if the string ends with " SL", so values would be transformed like this:

- "NAME SL" by "NAME S.L."
- "SLACK SL A" by "SLACK SL A"
- "NORMAL NAME" by "NORMAL NAME"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case`, but I don't think you want `replace()`.  Instead:

```
select (case when str like '% SL'
             then concat(left(str, length(str) - 2), 'S.L.')
             else str
        end)
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon! That made my day, I expressed bad myself, I didn't mean to use `replace()`, but to replace as a verb :) For instance, I needed to use `char_length` instead of `length` because I had special characters on some values.

Answer (score 0):

```
    select (case when COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%SL' then REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME,'SL', 'S.L')
         else COLUMN_NAME
    end) from TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: This is simmilar as answer from @GordonLinoff and as you can see here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=71fcd4a96f91038e566c32e61b93a956 in case if word has  SL two times then it will not work.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it